# Virtual Box Actual Size not increasing

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I've Ubuntu 14.0.4 & Windows 7 installed in Virtual Box.
I ran the below command to increase the virtual box allocation size

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "/home/myname/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7 RC/Windows 7 RC.vdi" --resize 52200
```

It gave me

```
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

And the size becomes:-

```
VBoxManage showhdinfo "/home/myname/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7 RC/Windows 7 RC.vdi"



UUID:           47c148a5-b97f-4cf3-97c1-69b39f9b2208
Parent UUID:    base
State:          created
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/myname/VirtualBox VMs/Windows 7 RC/Windows 7 RC.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Format variant: dynamic default
Capacity:       52200 MBytes
Size on disk:   25523 MBytes
```

The problem here is **Capacity** has been increased to **52 GB** but the **Actual Size is not increasing**.

**Format variant: dynamic default**  not fixed

I'd deeply appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!!

I went to Disk Management >> Disk Extend Volume >> Updated the disk size to Unallocated space.

Now it looks like below.

[image]